# How to get a given below value from json data?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I need to get the images array data how to put into the adapter and not required adapter code? Only loop and how to add that's important for me
and then after second I can access option_value array.
First all images can be accessed then after a option_value array.

```
  {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "id": "50",
        "seo_h1": "",
        "name": "Shirt 10001",
        "manufacturer": "",
        "sku": "",
        "model": "10001",
        "image": "http://api.yellowskydemo.com/image/cache/data/shirts/7228-500x500.jpg",
        "images": [
            "http://api.yellowskydemo.com/image/cache/data/shirts/13-500x500.jpg",
            "http://api.yellowskydemo.com/image/cache/data/shirts/302-500x500.jpg",
            "http://api.yellowskydemo.com/image/cache/data/shirts/5-500x500.jpg",
            "http://api.yellowskydemo.com/image/cache/data/shirts/205-500x500.jpg"
        ],
        "price": "$540.00",
        "rating": 0,
        "description": "<p>Fasten your fashion belts, for this is the ultimate edit of swanky casual wear by Ralph Lauren! For men who are born with a strong sense of style, the American powerhouse packs a colourful punch with this high-fash collection of shirts and sporty, monogrammed polos.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Fasten your fashion belts, for this is the ultimate edit of swanky casual wear by Ralph Lauren! For men who are born with a strong sense of style, the American powerhouse packs a colourful punch with this high-fash collection of shirts and sporty, monogrammed polos.</p>\r\n",
        "attribute_groups": [],
        "special": "",
        "discounts": [],
        "options": [
            {
                "name": "Size",
                "type": "select",
                "option_value": [
                    {
                        "image": "http://api.yellowskydemo.com/image/cache/no_image-100x100.jpg",
                        "price": "$50.00",
                        "price_prefix": "-",
                        "product_option_value_id": "17",
                        "option_value_id": "55",
                        "name": "L-40",
                        "quantity": "99"
                    },
                    {
                        "image": "http://api.yellowskydemo.com/image/cache/no_image-100x100.jpg",
                        "price": "$40.00",
                        "price_prefix": "+",
                        "product_option_value_id": "18",
                        "option_value_id": "57",
                        "name": "XXL-44",
                        "quantity": "100"
                    }
                ],
                "required": "1",
                "product_option_id": "227",
                "option_id": "14"
            }
        ],
        "minimum": "1",
        "meta_description": "",
        "meta_keyword": "",
        "tag": "",
        "upc": "",
        "ean": "",
        "jan": "",
        "isbn": "",
        "mpn": "",
        "location": "",
        "stock_status": "Out Of Stock",
        "manufacturer_id": null,
        "tax_class_id": "0",
        "date_available": "2014-08-12",
        "weight": "0.00000000",
        "weight_class_id": "1",
        "length": "0.00000000",
        "width": "0.00000000",
        "height": "0.00000000",
        "length_class_id": "1",
        "subtract": "0",
        "sort_order": "1",
        "status": "1",
        "date_added": "2014-08-13 12:05:56",
        "date_modified": "2015-06-30 11:19:39",
        "viewed": "8",
        "weight_class": "kg",
        "length_class": "cm",
        "reward": "0",
        "points": "0",
        "category": [
            {
                "name": "Shirts",
                "id": "59"
            },
            {
                "name": "Casual Shirts",
                "id": "60"
            }
        ],
        "quantity": "99",
        "reviews": {
            "review_total": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put it in http://jsonlint.com/ its not valid json

Comment: ravi now answer me.thank you so much for your 1st reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really look into How to parse JsonObject / JsonArray in android.

Please put your code of also what you have tried because people are here to help solve error/problem not to do coding.

Here is code from which you can Parse your json

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray imagesArray = dataObject.getJSONArray("images");
ArrayList<String> listOfImagesUrl = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < imagesArray.length(); i++)
{
     listOfImagesUrl.add(imagesArray.getString(i)); // listOfImages
}
```

// code for option value

```
JSONArray optionsArray = dataObject.getJSONArray("options");
for(int i = 0; i < optionsArray.length(); i++)
{
   JSONObject option = optionsArray.getJSONObject(i);
   JSONArray optionsValueArray = option.getJSONArray("option_value");
   for(int j = 0 ; j < optionsValueArray.length(); j++)
   {
      JSONObject optionValueObject = optionsValueArray.getJSONObject(j);
      String image = optionValueObject.getString("image");
      String price = optionValueObject.getString("price");
      String price_prefix = optionValueObject.getString("price_prefix");
      //same like this
   }
}
```